# Boost ASIO socket consumes file descriptors

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

I'm using Boost ASIO sockets for communicating with some remote devices under linux, but i have a problem when the endpoint is not reachable. First of all, here's the portion of code that shows this issue:

```
try {
   if(mysocket == NULL)
   {
      mysocket = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service);
   }
   mysocket->connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("192.168.0.12"), 1));
   printf("connected\n");
   return 0;
}
catch (std::exception &e)
{
   boost::system::error_code ec;
   mysocket->close(ec);
   delete mysocket;
   mysocket = NULL;
   printf("not connected %s\n", e.what());
}
```

By using this piece of code inside my class I get an increasing number of file descriptors of type eventfd, until all the available fds are used and the application crashes. Is there any problem with the code above? Why boost is not closing the file descriptors? I even delete the socket!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to run your code in an infinite loop, and it doesn't cause any resource leakage (boost 1.51, MSVC10, Win7). Could you please elaborate on your real scenario?

Comment: I think i solved this, and it should not be related to boost, but to someone else code not using virtual destructor in base class! This prevented some cleanup to be performed, thus leaving something around. Not sure this solves the issue, gotta test it first, but i guess i'm on the good way!

Comment: are you sure you're not leaking memory? Why not use a `std::shared_ptr` instead of a naked `mysocket` pointer?

Comment: @SamMiller thanks for the comment, actually new sockets were created continuously, the virtual destructor did the trick!

Comment: @cpl please add an answer so others encountering this problem know the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to not releasing resources, such as boost sockets. Those sockets left open files, which gradually reached the open file limit in my system, thus trying to open additional files resulted in an error. The actual exception was thrown by the boost UUID generator, which could not open files!